# how to zip a file having spaces in the filename in unix

Tags: bash, file, unix, zip, spaces

Is there a way we can zip a file having spaces in the filename? I am actually working on a scenario. Any help on how to handle this is extremely useful. Thanks in advance.

I have a text file containing list of multiple filenames. The terrible part is the filenames consists of a space in the end of the file name.
Example: Text file - DMI.txt

data in DMI.txt

```
DMI1 .txt
DMI2 .txt
DMI3 .txt
```

I need to zip each text file but the zip command is treating "DMI1" as 1 file and ".txt" as another file.

code

```
recdmi=$(cat $jobdir/import_dmi_hourly_file_list.txt)
while IFS= read -r recdmi
do
    echo $recdmi
    zip "$srcdir/\"${recdmi}\".zip" $srcdir/\"${recdmi}\"
    #mv "$srcdir/\"${recdmi}\".zip" $arcdir
    #rm $srcdir/\"${recdmi}\"
    echo "$srcdir/\"${recdmi}\".zip $srcdir/\"${recdmi}\""
done < $srcdir/import_dmi_hourly_file_list.txt
```

The output error is

```
/home/nkoka/nk_dmi_partner_ingestion/"DMI_2017-11-20_10 .txt".zip /home/nkoka/nk_dmi_partner_ingestion/"DMI_2017-11-20_10 .txt"

zip warning: name not matched: /home/nkoka/nk_dmi_partner_ingestion/"DMI_2017-11-20_10

zip warning: name not matched: .txt"

zip error: Nothing to do! (/home/nkoka/nk_dmi_partner_ingestion/"DMI_2017-11-20_10 .txt".zip)
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to put those quotation marks into the filename? If not, I think you should just use: zip "${srcdir}/${recdmi}.zip" "${srcdir}/${recdmi}"

Answer (score 1):

The escaped quotes are causing the quotes to be treated as literal parts of the filename. You don't need it.

```
zip "$srcdir/${recdmi}.zip" "$srcdir/${recdmi}"
```

Also, the first line

```
recdmi=$(cat $jobdir/import_dmi_hourly_file_list.txt)
```

is not needed, since you're immediately reassigning the variable with `read -r recdmi`.

Comment: still receiving the same error-------                                                                                                                 zip warning: name not matched: /home/nkoka/nk_dmi_partner_ingestion/DMI_2017-11-16_08
                                                                                                                 zip warning: name not matched: .txt

                                                                                                                 
zip error: Nothing to do! (/home/nkoka/nk_dmi_partner_ingestion/DMI_2017-11-16_08 .txt.zip)

Comment: Are you sure your filenames really have a space before `.txt`? Add the output of `ls "$srcdir"` to the question.